# OnItemClickListener on Fragment not work after exit from Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a **Fragment** that display item using **GridView**. When the item get click it will open new **Activity** and bring some Intent key from the Fragment.

> The problem is after i return from Activity to Fragment GridView
> OnItemClickListener not working. Only work once for every button.

It only work for the first time or i have go back to MainActivity and it will working again but only for once.

Here is my Fragment Code :

```
public class MaulidFragment extends Fragment implements Constant {
    private Context context;
    private KitabAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<KitabDataModel> arrayList;
    private String kitab_jenis, kitab_judul, kitab_file;
    private GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kitab_layout_gridview, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        loadGridView(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    }

    private void loadGridView(View view) {
        gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        arrayList = KitabData.getKitabData(context);
        adapter = new KitabAdapter(context, arrayList);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.filter("Maulid","");
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view1, position, id) -> {
            new AnimationUtils().pushdownAnimButtonKitab(view1);

            kitab_jenis = arrayList.get(position).getKitab_jenis();
            kitab_judul = arrayList.get(position).getKitab_judul();
            kitab_file = arrayList.get(position).getFile();

            Intent intent = new Intent(requireContext(), KitabBookPDF.class);
            intent.putExtra(pdf_file, kitab_file);
            intent.putExtra(toolbar_title, kitab_jenis + " " + kitab_judul);
            startActivity(intent);
        });
    }
}
```

This is the Activity :

```
public class KitabBookPDF extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnPageChangeListener, Constant {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    Integer pageNumber = 0;
    PDFView pdfView;

    // Intent
    Intent intent;
    Bundle extras;

    String pdfFile, toolbarTitle;

    long lastPress;
    Toast backpressToast;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kit_pdfview);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        getDataIntent();

        //PDF
        pdfView = findViewById(R.id.pdfView);

        // Toolbar setup
        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(view -> onBackPressed());

        new PDFViewUtils().setPdfViewLocalFile(this, pdfView, pdfFile, pageNumber);
 }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime - lastPress > backPressKitabPage) {
            backpressToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getText(R.string.back_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            backpressToast.show();
            lastPress = currentTime;
        } else {
            if (backpressToast != null) backpressToast.cancel();
            showInterstitial();
        }
    }

    public void onPageChanged(int page, int pageCount) {
        pageNumber = page;
        String judulhalaman = toolbarTitle;
        toolbar.setTitle(String.format("%s - %s / %s", judulhalaman, page + 1, pageCount));
    }

    private void getDataIntent(){
        intent = getIntent();
        extras = intent.getExtras();

        assert extras != null;
        pdfFile = extras.getString(pdf_file);
        toolbarTitle = extras.getString(toolbar_title);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        pdfView.destroyDrawingCache();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        pdfView.destroyDrawingCache();
    }
}
```

What that i missing here. How to fix this?

Comment: can you move `gridView.setOnItemClickListener` from `loadGridView` to `onResume()` and see

Comment: @Zain i try that, the prolem still the same.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you override `onBackPressed()` but not call it's super. When you overrides this one, you should save `super.onBackPressed()` in it if you want to be able go back :)
So, you code should looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentTime - lastPress > backPressKitabPage) {
        backpressToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), getText(R.string.back_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        backpressToast.show();
        lastPress = currentTime;
    } else {
        if (backpressToast != null) backpressToast.cancel();
        showInterstitial();
    }
}
```

or if you need to go back only in case of `currentTime - lastPress > backPressKitabPage`, so move it inside if block :)

Comment: that not the case, i already try to remove the `@override onBackPressed()` . The problem still exist.

Comment: Ok, to solve this case please write some logs for fragment to check which methods is not called. I think, that on your fragment recreation method 'loadgridview' is not called, so your clicklistener don't work after recreation. If I am right, fragment lifecycle will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is conflict with Liblary

> com.github.thekhaeng:pushdown-anim-click:1.1.1